# find error in c program : trying to make a custom strlenx function which counts the size of array?

Tags: c

This program complies fine but on running it stops in terminal and doest show any output i have to stop it manually by pressing "control + z".
I am expecting it to output size of string "hello , world"

```
include <stdio.h>

int strlenx(char *s);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("\n");
  int a[10];
  int size;

  size =  strlenx("hello , world");
  printf("size  = %d", size);

  printf("\n\n");
}


int strlenx(char *s)
{
  int n;

  for(n =0; *s != '\0'; n++)
    n++;

  return n;
}
```

Comment: is there a reason not to use [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/)

Comment: i was trying to implement my own for practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your strlenx function, you are never incrementing your pointer `s`. Your for loop should be:

```
for(n =0; *s != '\0'; s++)
    n++;
```